# How to wrap retrofit response with generic response

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I am following after "Google Best Practices" and they suggested to add Generic response handler.

I added This generic response handler, I wrap my model with the response handler, but I've really hard time to understand how can I use this.

For my understanding, I need to call to `create` method, and pass response or error and this class handles all the rest, and return if it was empty/sucess/error.

Where am I calling this create method?

This is currently my approach, and obviously it's now working( getting `Failed to invoke private com.example.resclassex.utils.GenericApiResponse() with no args` error)

This is the generic class:

```
sealed class GenericApiResponse<T> {

    companion object {
        private val TAG: String = "AppDebug"


        fun <T> create(error: Throwable): ApiErrorResponse<T> {
            return ApiErrorResponse(error.message ?: "unknown error")
        }

        fun <T> create(response: Response<T>): GenericApiResponse<T> {

            if(response.isSuccessful){
                val body = response.body()
                if (body == null || response.code() == 204) {
                    return ApiEmptyResponse()
                }
                else if(response.code() == 401){
                    return ApiErrorResponse("401 Unauthorized. Token may be invalid.")
                }
                else {
                    return ApiSuccessResponse(body = body)
                }
            }
            else{
                val msg = response.errorBody()?.string()
                val errorMsg = if (msg.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    response.message()
                } else {
                    msg
                }
                return ApiErrorResponse(errorMsg ?: "unknown error")
            }
        }
    }
}

class ApiEmptyResponse<T> : GenericApiResponse<T>()

data class ApiSuccessResponse<T>(val body: T) : GenericApiResponse<T>() {}

data class ApiErrorResponse<T>(val errorMessage: String) : GenericApiResponse<T>()
```

call enque:

```
    private fun getMovies() {
    val call = RetrofitService.moviesApiService.getAllMovies(Constants.API_KEY)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<GenericApiResponse<AllMovies>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<GenericApiResponse<AllMovies>>,
            response: Response<GenericApiResponse<AllMovies>>
        ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ")
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GenericApiResponse<AllMovies>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: $t")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, but the issue with mine implementation was that coroutines and suspend function `CallAdapter` was unable to convert response into `liveData wrapper` around `GenericResponse<NetworkResponse>`.

I removed the suspend function and I no longer I got Failed to invoke private com.example.resclassex.utils.GenericApiResponse() with no args.

You can share the API interface's return type.

You can also debug the `callAdapterFactory` if correct adapter is returned by factory.

Answer (score 0):

I built a base structure that followed Google's recommendation. You can check it here: (branch : sample)

https://github.com/frank-nhatvm/fatherofapps

Take note that: sample branch .
In this source code, you can find how to define genetic class and how to use it with network layer. And how to call it in VIewModel, Repository, Service